# Reshuffle array based on whether a value is present, and by an integer

Tags: php, arrays

I'm really struggling to work out how to sort a large array.

The array is of property data. There are two crucial pieces of data that I need to use to arrange the array in an order. They are:

- number of bedrooms
- availability status

Here's an example of the array

```
[0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["location"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["street_name"]=>
      string(10) "Derby Road"
    }
    ["info"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["status"]=>
      string(9) "available"
    }
    ["specs"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["bedroom_number"]=>
      string(1) "7"
    }
  }
```

The `status` key can be set to `let`, `available` or a few other options. What I need to do is make any property that is `let` fall to the bottom of the array *but in bedroom number order descending*.

So, I guess these are the two rules:

- Properties must always appear in bedroom number descending. So 7 bedrooms should be at the top of the list and 1 bedroom should be at the bottom
- 'Let' status properties should always be the lowest within their bedroom number, e.g:

  `7 bedroom property - available`

  `7 bedroom property - available`

  `7 bedroom property - let`

  `6 bedroom property - available`

  `7 bedroom property - let`

  `4 bedroom property - available`

  `3 bedroom property - let`

I'm aware of the existence of `usort()` but I'm just not sure how to arrange within the function for this sort of arranging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and then use the array keys to do the sorting.

Maybe this setup can help you:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        "location" => array("street_name" => "Derby Road"),
        "info" => array("status" => "available"),
        "specs" => array("bedroom_number" => "7")
    ),
    array(
        "location" => array("street_name" => "Derby Road"),
        "info" => array("status" => "let"),
        "specs" => array("bedroom_number" =>"5")
    ),
    array(
        "location" => array("street_name" => "Derby Road"),
        "info" => array("status" => "let"),
        "specs" => array("bedroom_number" =>"7")
    ),
    array(
        "location" => array("street_name" => "Derby Road"),
        "info" => array("status" => "available"),
        "specs" => array("bedroom_number" =>"5")
    ),
    array(
        "location" => array("street_name" => "Derby Road"),
        "info" => array("status" => "available"),
        "specs" => array("bedroom_number" =>"7")
    )
);
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a["specs"]["bedroom_number"] === $b["specs"]["bedroom_number"]) {
        return ($a["info"]["status"] !== "let") ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return ($a["specs"]["bedroom_number"] > $b["specs"]["bedroom_number"]) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($array, "cmp");
```

Comment: What does the string 'cmp' mean? I'm confused as to what you're passing to the function. Where is $a and $b coming from?

Comment: That is how the php [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function works. "cmp" is the name of the function (in the example `function cmp`) that is being used to do the sorting. $a and $b are the values that it uses to do the comparison.

Comment: Thanks. This answer worked perfectly. I'm just trying my best to actually understand the mechanics behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried array_multisort function ? here is an example:

```
<?php
function array_orderby()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    $data = array_shift($args);
    foreach ($args as $n => $field) {
        if (is_string($field)) {
            $tmp = array();
            foreach ($data as $key => $row)
                $tmp[$key] = $row[$field];
            $args[$n] = $tmp;
            }
    }
    $args[] = &$data;
    call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $args);
    return array_pop($args);
}
?>
```

The sorted array is now in the return value of the function instead of being passed by reference.

```
<?php
$data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 2);
$data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 1);
$data[] = array('volume' => 85, 'edition' => 6);
$data[] = array('volume' => 98, 'edition' => 2);
$data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 6);
$data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 7);

// Pass the array, followed by the column names and sort flags
$sorted = array_orderby($data, 'volume', SORT_DESC, 'edition', SORT_ASC);
?>
```

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php